# Can't preview files nor open them via Drive app

Tags: google-drive, nexus-6

Is it just me? Or anyone else having issues with Drive app on their Nexus 6?

Nexus 10 & Nexus 5 work just fine.

Tried removing it, rebooting, reinstalling -
Log out & logging back in -
Clearing cache (and data)

There a no precise thumbnails. The documents are there, but won't open, like they aren't really there.